# Solving $\sin(\arcsin(a-x) -c) = \sin(\arcsin(b+x)+\pi-c) + d$ for $x$

Tags: trigonometry

> Find $x$ in terms of the constants: $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$.
>   $$\sin(\arcsin(a-x) -c) = \sin(\arcsin(b+x)+\pi-c) + d$$

(Assume $d$ is around $.01$-$.21$.)

I don't how to solve this problem or if it is even possible to solve. Please, help me solve it or show me why it is an impossible math question.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference ) to make your questions more readable.

Comment: It really depends on the constants: if $d = 100$ for example, it would be impossible (because $\sin$ can only get so big).

Answer (score 0):

Use the identity $\sin(x+y) = \sin x\cos y+\cos x\sin y$ to expand the equation,

$$\sin[\arcsin(a-x) -c] = \sin[\arcsin(b+x)+\pi-c] + d$$

to

$$(a-x)\cos c-\sqrt{1-(a-x)^2}\sin c = -(b+x)\cos c+\sqrt{1-(b+x)^2}\sin c + d$$

where $\cos (\arcsin t) = \sqrt{1-t^2}$ is used. Rearrange the resulting equation to obtain the following,

$$\sqrt{1-(a-x)^2}  = r-\sqrt{1-(b+x)^2}$$

where

$$r = \frac{(a+b)\cos c-d}{\sin c}$$

Then, square both sides (twice) to remove square-roots and you end up with a standard quadratic equation in $x$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad could help